# HTML/Javascript, table with multiple filters, once again (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, filter, html-table, filtering

Okay, so I'm creating an interactive table that's starting to be almost what I'm aiming for, but not quite. Frustratingly close to it. I have been digging this subject for couple of weeks but now it feels I'm on an dead end.

Basically only thing I'm currently lacking is stacking filters. This subject has been discussed quite a lot here too, but I don't seem to find working solution. it also does have working sorting system which has the same issue, but that's probably something I can live with.

In the code, there are very clear issues (else {loadTableData(trailerTableData);} being the most obvious which also causes checkboxes to behave more like radio buttons) and I have couple of things in my mind but I'm not sure how to implement them.

Creating new table after filtering is not a good solution since it would not work with attribute column, where you'd need to be able to see multiple attributes.

Looping through all the filters is probably one solution but things being in local scope is an obstacle.

During the last night I thought that looping through checkboxes might also be an option, since it's not so critical if that search field is not stackable. This last one would probably be the simpliest solution..?

```js
//TABLE DATA
let trailerTableData = [
{pv:"ABC1234",side:"On", side2:"-", attribute:"2"},
{pv:"WRB2345",side:"-", side2:"On(1)", attribute:"3"},
{pv:"WRC4567",side:"-", side2:"-", attribute: "2"},
{pv:"RTD7890",side:"On(2)", side2: "On", attribute: "1"}
];

window.onload = () => {
    loadTableData(trailerTableData);
};

function loadTableData(trailerTableData) {
    let tableBody = document.getElementById ('trailerTableData');
    let dataHtml = '';

    for(let trailer of trailerTableData) {
    dataHtml += `<tr>

    <td>${trailer.pv}</td>
    <td>${trailer.side}</td>
    <td>${trailer.side2}</td>
    <td>${trailer.attribute}</td>
    </tr>`;
    }

    tableBody.innerHTML = dataHtml;
}

// INPUT SEARCH FOR PV
function filterTrailers() {
    let input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("inputTrailerSearch");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("trailerTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}





// FUNCTION FOR CHECKBOX SIDE 1. PROBABLY NOT A GOOD SOLUTION BUT THIS ACTUALLY WORKS EXACTLY AS IT SHOULD, IF STACKING FILTERS WOULD NOT BE REQUIRED.
function filterSide1() {
    let input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("checkboxSide1Id");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("trailerTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    if (input.checked != false) {
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
            } else {
                loadTableData(trailerTableData);
    }
}

// FUNCTION FOR CHECKBOX SIDE 2, SO IT'S THE SAME THAN WITH SIDE 1.
function filterSide2() {
    let input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("checkboxSide2Id");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("trailerTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    if (input.checked != false) {
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
            } else {
                loadTableData(trailerTableData);
    }
}





// THE REST 3 FUNCTIONS ARE FOR ATTIBUTE. ONLY CHANGE IS THAT THERE'S NO LOOP FOR FILTER. ONLY CHECKING IF VALUE IS 1. OR 2. OR 3.
function filterAttribute1() {
    let input, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("checkboxAttribute1Id");
    table = document.getElementById("trailerTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    if (input.checked != false) {
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue == 1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
            } else {
                loadTableData(trailerTableData);
    }
}

function filterAttribute2() {
    let input, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("checkboxAttribute2Id");
    table = document.getElementById("trailerTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    if (input.checked != false) {
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue == 2) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
            } else {
                loadTableData(trailerTableData);
    }
}

function filterAttribute3() {
    let input, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("checkboxAttribute3Id");
    table = document.getElementById("trailerTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    if (input.checked != false) {
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue == 3) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
            } else {
                loadTableData(trailerTableData);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36)">
   
          <fieldset class="inputFieldset" style="width: 290px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0)"; >

        <div class="checkboxDiv">
            <input type="text" id="inputTrailerSearch" class="inputTrailerSearchField" maxlength="10" onkeyup="filterTrailers()" type="search" placeholder="search pv" onfocus="this.value=''">
        </div>
        
        <p></p>

        <div class="checkboxDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" name="side1" id="checkboxSide1Id" onchange="filterSide1()" class="checkboxSide1 checkbox">
            <label for="checkboxSideId" class="labels">SIDE 1</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkboxDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" name="side2" id="checkboxSide2Id" onchange="filterSide2()" class="checkboxSide2 checkbox">
            <label for="checkboxSide2Id" class="labels">SIDE 2</label>   
        </div>

        <p></p>

        <div class="checkboxDiv">
                <input type="checkbox" name="attribute1" id="checkboxAttribute1Id" onchange="filterAttribute1()" class="checkboxAttribute1 checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxAttribute1Id" class="labels">ATTRIBUTE 1</label>   
            </div>
        
        
        <div class="checkboxDiv">
                <input type="checkbox" name="attribute2" id="checkboxAttribute2Id" onchange="filterAttribute2()" class="checkboxAttribute2 checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxAttribute2Id" class="labels">ATTRIBUTE  2</label>   
            </div>
        
        <div class="checkboxDiv">
                <input type="checkbox" name="attribute3" id="checkboxAttribute3Id" onchange="filterAttribute3()" class="checkboxAttribute3 checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxAttribute3Id" class="labels">ATTRIBUTE  3</label>   
            </div>



         </fieldset>
         <p></p>
         <fieldset class="inputFieldset" style="width: 290px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0)";>
            <table id="trailerTable" border="2" bordercolor="#000000" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)";>
                <thead id="tableHead">
                <tr>
                <th onclick="sortColumn('pv')">PV</th>
                <th onclick="sortColumn('side')">SIDE1</th>
                <th onclick="sortColumn('side2')">SIDE2</th>
                <th onclick="sortColumn('attribute')">ATTRIBUTE</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="trailerTableData"></tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <script src="TRASH.JS" type="text/javascript"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so basically, only one checkbox should be checked and based on that table should be display, right ?

Comment: Oh no, you should be able to check all the checkboxes needed. So basically it should filter the data so if, for example, checkbox for Side 1 and Side 2 are checked, result would basically be RTD7890, since there is that "On" text from both of the columns.

If you would check Side 2 and Attribute 3, result would be WRB2345.

Comment: Second example was not too clear since result actually is WRB2345 if you check Attribute 3 last. But it should show the same result if you would check Attribute 3 first and Side 2 second. One more example would be if you would check Side 2 and Attribute 2. It should not show anything since conditions are not met.

Comment: your comment is confusing same as your question, when i check attribute 3 first and side 2 second, you want both data or only last checked value or first checked value.

Comment: Okay, how should I put this.. It should seek values from both of these columns, but if you check Attribute 3 and then Side 2, it should still show just WRB2345 since that's the only PV with Attribute value 3. Now it would also show RTD7890, but that should be filtered out since it's value is 1, which it should not show at all when that Attribute 3 is checked.

Comment: So if you check Side 1, it shows only those rows that's column Side 1 has text "On" in them. Then if you check also Side 2, it should show only those rows that have value "On" in both columns of Side 1 and Side 2. So it's main purpose is to filter out all the rows that does not have values (Side 1 and Side 2), or in the case of Attributes, that's value is something else than selected attribute value. If you check Attribute 1 and Attribute 2, you should only see those rows that has Attribute value of 1 and 2.